# custom css breaks with bootstrap grids

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My custom vertical-side-navigation bar works fine by itself.
Here's a plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pLXogXuPiYwulcuzExMh

However when introduced within a bootstrap grid, the same navbar breaks. Plnkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/50G3o3ekNMR8qx2Be3rG

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1">
          <ng-include src="'nav.html'"></ng-include>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-11">
          This is content section
        </div>
      </div>
```

I can fix this using some hacks like adding min-height property to the class

> .vertical-side-bar

However, I do not believe that is the right way to do it. I am missing something here conceptually.

Could anyone please point out what's wrong?

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing where the navbar "breaks"...

Comment: did you open both plnkr links ?

Comment: Of course.  Nothing jumped out.  Saying "it breaks" is a description I'd expect to hear from a project manager.  I actually don't see a vertical bar in either plunkr.

Comment: "it breaks" is quiet sufficient when one opens both plnkr. There is only one element on the page.. the vertical navigation bar. when it appears complete on one page and weird on another .. no further explanation is needed. If nothing is showing up when you open up both the plnkr..then there are other issues that you need to address instead of my technical vocab. Other users are able to view the difference.

Comment: There are issues with your plunkr that I need to address?  Ha!

Comment: now you have issues comprehending ..

Comment: It's pretty clear you have no idea how to communicate at this point. "If nothing is showing up when you open up both the plnkr..then there are other issues that you need to address" is a verbatim quote.  I have to fix your plunkr before I fix your code?  Good luck in life, man.

Comment: @JamesHans Your Plunk is broken because of the lack of a CSS file for your nav.  If there are other issues, you need to fix your Plunk a bit to make them clear.  Your Plunk was incomplete, as im1dermike said.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious issue in your Plunk is that you are not calling the nav.css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css" />
```

[Try this minor update to your Plunk here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/9eqDkU?p=preview)

Now all that is missing is the background color and such.  That shouldn't be difficult to add back.  Your layout is basically working, though you need to make it fill the container width instead of being fixed width (I added that in my plunk).

But bear in mind that you can't get a fixed width column in Bootstrap 3 like you seem to be expecting.  A column will always be 1/12th of the width of the screen.  Also, you should start with columns defined for xs and then specify sm, md, or lg if they need to be different.

For example, you might need 3 xs columns to fit your content (col-xs-3), but only 1 in a large device (col-lg-1).